# manipulate browsing history programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm developing a shopping site

User moves from

product-detail -> cart -> checkout steps -> order confirm

When a user arrives order confirm page, if he hits back button, I think he should go to the page before the `cart` which is product-detail page in the above flow.

- edit

He might go back and forth between cart and checkout steps.

I guess I need a way to mark these pages for deletion.

Does history api offer a way to mark pages so that later one can remove them from the history?

Comment: HTML5 History api. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Comment: @EricGuan I've edited the question a bit.

Answer (score 0):

If you use this:

```
window.history.go(-3); //jumps back 3 in the history
```

And the user then browses to a new page, it will delete the forward history. So, to prevent browsing forward you could go back further and then forward.

```
window.history.go(-4); //jumps back 3 in the history

window.history.go(1); //erase the history
```